# Google uses wrong image to display product in Google Image Search

Tags: schema.org, google-image-search

I have a problem with Google associating the wrong image with our products when they are display in Image Search.

For some reason, the main image of our products, which has more desirable data (alt tags, higher resolution, placed first as product image, not tampered with), is discarded.Instead, Google chooses the last loaded image for a product, which has no alt data, worse resolution, watermark dynamically added (it's not even .jpg), or just blank white image with the watermark.

I have Schema.org microdata set up dynamically for each product. I've removed the "additional_image" tag, using only "image", still no success.

-- Edit --

Ex. 1:
https://www.royalora.hu/vostok-europe-karora/gaz-14-limousine-karora/560A517

[image: 560A517 product search]

The displayed image is the last one in the gallery.

Html of the displayed image:

```
<img src="(removed, around 1000 characters long due to added watermark)" alt="" class=" wm-ajandek" style="display: inline;">
```

Ex. 2: https://www.royalora.hu/vostok-europe-karora/energia-karora/575A539B
[image: 575A539B product search]

The displayed image is the second out of four in the gallery.
Html of the displayed image:

```
<img src="/shopimg/575A539B_2.jpg" alt="" class=" wm-nocontext wm-termek" style="display: inline;">
```

Ex. 3: https://www.royalora.hu/festina-karora/the-originals-karora/F20330-2
[image: f20330/2 product search]

The displayed image is the first and correct one.
Html of the displayed image:

```
<img src="/shopimg/F203302.jpg" alt="Festina The Originals férfi karóra - F20330/2" class="main-pic wm-nocontext wm-termek" style="">
```

Comment: Does Google image search show product badges for your images? If the answer is no, then I think Google is not picking the schema structured data. You should inspect the reasons for the same.

Comment: Schema works fine, the product badge is there. Feels strange though that pricing and availaibilty is correct, but the image gets chosen randomly.

Comment: Is the image URL being picked correct while validating with https://search.google.com/test/rich-results? (under product data-type)

Comment: I've tested it before and every information is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried inspecting few other sites (using the keyword 560A517) that are eligible to show structured data. I could find instances in which the images displayed were **different** from the structured data images.

Probably Google is picking the best image from a product page based on several other signals in addition to the structured data image.

I believe the reason could be one of the following.

1. The image may have fallen short of guidelines like those for quality, relevance, originality, etc. For example, if many sites use **the same or similar images** for a popular product, I don't think Google will flood all the image results with the identical product pictures despite structured data. Ref: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/sd-policies

2. The image may have fallen short of one of the data-type specific guidelines as outlined in https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product#product (check for "image" under "Required Properties").

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your site to Google MyBusiness and use the “Add Product” feature. It may take a little bit, but Google should change the image of the product in search as long as you set the URL correctly in the product listing.
Let me know if it works

Comment: We have over 2000 products actively changing. As far as I've seen, Google MyBusiness doesn't have batch upload feature, right?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like it. Can you share the HTML code you use for one of the products that displays the wrong image? Please show the code and a screenshot of the product on google that is displaying incorrectly. You can edit your original post and put it at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: Added 2 different wrong examples, and a correct one.

Comment: Make sure the correct image is of better quality than the others, and be sure to fill out the alt tag on the correct one. The other answer may also give you more insight.